# SOLR edismax search with expressions

Tags: solr, edismax

I have a field "spell" with text:

> piazzata apposta apposta per tenere al caldo queste sue prime ore al
>   mondo

How can I search something like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q={!type=edismax qf=spell v='apposta apposta per'} OR {!type=edismax qf=spell v='sue prime ore al'} - incorrect
```

I mean how can I use expressions **AND/OR/NOT** in edismax query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your configurations simpler

```
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="defType">edismax</str>
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <str name="qf">spell</str>
        <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

and try -

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=(apposta apposta per) OR (sue prime ore al)
```

Comment: I added this instruction in solrconfig.xml restarted solr and tryed this query but solr returned me all records

Comment: Its seems it is or for terms inside (). Try q=(apposta AND apposta AND  per) OR (sue AND prime AND ore AND al) or q=("apposta apposta per") OR ("sue prime ore al")

Comment: AND and OR working fine for me now. Thanks. But how can I add NOT expression?

Comment: e.g. q=(commercial AND banking) NOT (Wells Fargo)